# nginx Document Root in SubFolder

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have this conf:

```
location /site {
            error_log /var/log/nginx/site_error.log ;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/site_access.log ;
            alias /opt/www/old_site;
            try_files $uri  $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args ;
            location ~*\.php {                       
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;

            }
}
```

If I acces `www.mysite.com/site` all works, except that links dispersed in the webpage as e.g.

```
<script src="/js/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
```

do not (NOT FOUND).

The `Document Root` is supposed to be `/opt/www/old_site`, isnt'it?

Comment: The requested URI is `/js/select2/js/select2.full.min.js`, which does not match `location /site` as it does not begin with `/site`. You need to fix your application so that the embedded links use the correct URL.

Comment: But an URI starting with / is supposed to begin from the DOCUMEN ROOT, isnt'it? In this case it should render to old_site/js/.. I have been provided with a legacy application tied with .htaccess. There is a way to not rewrite all the application?

Comment: Which would match `location /` and not `location /site`

Comment: Why isn't this app being placed in its own subdomain? That would prevent the problem.

Comment: Ok, but it would be a tedious work! Suppose that I have a js folder in the root of the application, under old_site. How to access those files under old_site/js/* from any point in the application, even in a subfolder e.g. old_site/manuals/index.php?